# Python code, copy dimension from one object to another

Tags: python, transforms

I require some help please. I select one object (A), then shift to select another (B). Then I require some python code to copy the X dimension from (A) to (B).
The X dimensions for both objects are the same after the script is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swap A and B**

For the most part, blender works the other way. The last selected object is the active object,aka  the `context.object` or `context.active_object` used by operators. An attribute of the context object can be assinged to all the other selected objects, in the list `context.selected_objects`

Hence select B [C, D, E, F...] then A, A has context. The x dimension of A is set as the X dimension of B and other non active selected objects.  (and lazily A too not that it matters in this case as it is same)

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
x = context.object.dimensions.x
for o in context.selected_objects:
    o.dimensions.x = x
```

Note: if an objects data has a zero dimension, for instance default plane in Z. there is no way of scaling to make its z dimension non zero.

Comment: How would you change this to get all x,y,z  dimensions to be the same length?

Comment: `ob.dimensions = (x,) * 3`